# Steam web browser does not load pages (steam store)

Tags: steam, browser

[The program Steam will not load web pages inside of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Videq.png), This is an essential function if you want to view products on their network. Everything else in the program is functional, but the web browser just won't work.

I looked for a fix on other websites and have only been able to find the windows fix:

Close Steam. Go to:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Steam\htmlcache`

Empty the folder. Restart Steam.`

I have already tried uninstalling steam:

`sudo apt-get remove steam`

`sudo apt-get purge steam`

Strangely, that didn't work. When I searched for Steam using this command:

`sudo dpkg -l`

I could not find the package.

So, I gave up on using the terminal and went to the software center and uninstalled it.

Additionally, I tried to find user date in `/home/cory/.local/share`, but it is empty.

After reinstalling it (and even installing it on another user account on the same computer), I still get a black loading screen.

Any ideas what might be keeping the browser from loading web pages?

Comment: Try to search for `htmlcache` with `find -type d -name htmlcache`. Anyway I have the same issue and removing this directory didn't help me.